# Stop execution in Activity when starting a new activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm evaluating a case and the truth is not the way I want. Depending on a true or false value, the application must do something, if true, should go to another view so I do the following:

```
if(metodoRut){
   inscripcion = nueva.getInscripcionByRut(rut,codigoEvento ,this);
   if(nueva.getCantidadInscripciones(this, rut) > 1){
      Intent intent = new Intent(this,ValidacionMultiple.class);
      System.out.println(intent.toString());
      startActivity(intent);
    }
}else{
   inscripcion = nueva.getInscripcion(rawResult.getText(),codigoEvento,this);
}
/* 
 * more code
 * /
```

If I need to run it meets the Intent, but that happens. Sign in if makes everything that comes after the IF and then launch my new view.

Comment: Theres a translation issue here, you might need to try to reword the question. as a note there is a portuguese StackOverflow which might make things easier http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: actually is spanish, but I didn´t get the question

Comment: Apologize for my English, so I wanted to explain is that even after call start activity were still running but the response actions below me fix everything!

Comment: I know you speak spanish, but there isnt a spanish forum as far as I know, so I thought the translation to portuguese should be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you were trying to say it's that the code you have where the `more code` comment is executes even after you called `startActivity`

The easiest fix for that (which may not be the best or cleanest solution) would be to call `finish()` immediately after `startActivity()`